# Calculate average velocity

Tags: linear-algebra

If I skate a distance of 80km and back in 4 hours, and my average speed when going back is 7kilometers per hour lower then the first part of my trip, what's the average velocity I had in part one of my trip and in part 2 of my trip?

Comment: I got nothing further than setting up a most certainly wrong equation to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t\ hrs$ be the time taken to travel a distance of $80\ km$ in first part then average velocity in first part of trip $$\color{blue}{\bar{v_1}=\frac{80}{t}}$$
then $4-t$ is the time taken to travel a distance of $80\ km$ in second part of trip then average velocity in second part $$\color{blue}{\bar{v_2}=\frac{80}{4-t}}$$
now, we have $$\bar{v_1}-\bar{v_2}=7$$
$$\frac{80}{t}-\frac{80}{4-t}=7$$ $$7t^2-188t+320=0\implies t=\frac{94\pm2\sqrt{1649}}{7}$$
But the time taken in the first part of the trip, $t$ is such that $\ \  \ \ 0<t<4$

hence, one should get time taken in the first part of trip, $t=\frac{94-2\sqrt{1649}}{7}\approx 1.826319712\ hrs$

then substituting the value of $t$, find the average velocities $\bar{v_1}$ & $\bar{v_2}$ in both the parts of trip